# Extending C++ with scripting

Tags: c++, swig

I am thinking in the possibility of extending a C++ program calling a scripting languages. I have been searching and reading SWIG documentation, but all the examples speaks only about calling C++ libraries from scripting language, but not in the other way. Is possible with SWIG calling to PHP, or Java from C++ program? If it's not possible, what could better, boost.python or LUA?

Comment: google 'embedding' rather than 'extending' for whatever scripting langauges you are interested in (SWIG is for 'extending')

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040669/how-can-i-implement-a-c-class-in-python-to-be-called-by-c is looking at the same problem with Python.

Comment: It is pretty easy to embed an interpreter in C++ for perl python lua [scripting language here]

Answer (score 0):

its not c++ but it should work

```
char *argsa[] = {"/bin/bash","-c","script",(char *) 0 };
int execReturn = execv("/bin/bash",argsa);
```