# build error while exposing classes to python using boost.python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I have some issue with exposing abstract class to python using Boost.Python lib. I am using 1_53_0 boost and Python 33.

There is a similar thread related to this issue.
([How can I implement a C++ class in Python, to be called by C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040669/how-can-i-implement-a-c-class-in-python-to-be-called-by-c)) I was following [eudoxos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761090/eudoxos) response where he makes a wrapper around abstract class Base, which has a method returning string type.

I'm doing something similar but I constantly get a compilation error:

- Error    1   error C2668: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded function   d:\temp\example\example.h   20
- 8 IntelliSense: more than one user-defined conversion from "boost::python::detail::method_result" to "std::string" applies:  d:\temp\example\example.h   20

The above errors are related to the line:

```
return this->get_override("getName")();
```

From my example shown bellow:

```
#include <string>
#include "boost/python.hpp"

class Person {

public:

    virtual std::string getName() { return "Base"; };

    virtual void setName(std::string name) {};

};

class PersonWrap : public Person, public boost::python::wrapper<Person>
{

public:

    std::string getName()
    {
        return this->get_override("getName")();
    }

    void setName(std::string name)
    {
        this->get_override("setName")();
    }
};

class Student : public Person {

public:

    std::string getName() { return myName; };

    void setName(std::string name) { myName = name; };

    std::string myName;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    boost::python::class_<PersonWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Person")
        .def("getName", (&Person::getName))
        .def("setName", (&Person::setName))
    ;

    boost::python::class_<Student, boost::python::bases<Person>>("Student")
        .def("getName", (&Student::getName))
        .def("setName", (&Student::setName))
    ;
}
```

Any comments are appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: If `Person` is pure virtual, why isn't `getName() = 0` and `setName(...) = 0` in their declarations? Are you providing implementations elsewhere? If so, is it correct to wrap `&Person::getName` with `boost::python::pure_virtual`?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I didn't realize the code doesn't match my issue. However, it still doesn't solve my initial problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to this issue and it works like this:

```
std::string getName()
{
    //return this->get_override("getName")();
    return boost::python::call<std::string>(this->get_override("getName")());
}
```

However, according to [the boost python documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html) this has to be used only for MSVC6/7, which is not my case since I am using VS2010 (MSVC 10.0).