# Embedding the Python Interpreter and using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a solution in VisualStudio that contains two projects. The first project is a C++ console application with Pure Embedding as follows:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
int i;

if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
    return 1;
}

Py_Initialize();
pName = PyUnicode_FromString(argv[1]);
/* Error checking of pName left out */

pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);

if (pModule != NULL) {
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);
    /* pFunc is a new reference */

    if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
        pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
        for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
            pValue = PyLong_FromLong(atoi(argv[i + 3]));
            if (!pValue) {
                Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                return 1;
            }
            /* pValue reference stolen here: */
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
        }
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        if (pValue != NULL) {
            printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
            Py_DECREF(pValue);
        }
        else {
            Py_DECREF(pFunc);
            Py_DECREF(pModule);
            PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
            PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
    }
    Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
}
else {
    PyErr_Print();
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
Py_Finalize();
return 0;}
```

When running a python file any works perfectly.

The second project contains some C++ classes compiled with SWIG. This project works perfectly using the Python script as below.

```
import example 
x = 42 
y = 105 
example.gcd = g (x, y)
```

My problem is when the console application needs to run a python script that imports classes from the SWIG. If I use the python lib python32.lib works commenting on some parts of the code as "Py_DECREF (pArgs)" but I can only run once the python script, the second attempt, an error occurs the read access of memory. If I use python32_d.lib the construction of the modules do not work if the file import python SWIG:

```
pName = PyUnicode_FromString(argv[1]);
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
```

NOTE: I need to compile in DEBUG mode and not in RELEASE mode.

Comment: Have you seen my generic answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040669/how-can-i-implement-a-c-class-in-python-to-be-called-by-c/9042139#9042139 (I can't really help with the Windows aspect though I'm afraid).