# How can I use Python to access C++ objects at runtime?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010, runtime, swig

I have an existing C++ application and have wrapped a few of the classes with python using SWIG. What do I have to do next to be able to open a python console while the C++ app is running and access its runtime objects (of the classes I have already wrapped)?

Comment: In general, you *don't* get access to the memory of another process.

Comment: The most obvious solution would be to embed a python interpreter in your C++ app. There's a part named "extending and embedding" in python's doc IIRC

Comment: @chepner duh, that's why I'm asking this.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, Thanks, but unfortunately the "Embedding Python in C++" section is two sentences long and explains very little.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040669/how-can-i-implement-a-c-class-in-python-to-be-called-by-c answer this for you? There's a complete example for both SWIG and Boost.Python there.

Comment: @Flexo, yes. It seems all I needed was the word "embed" and now I can find tons of information, but that particular answer was the most helpful.