# How to debug a python class casted/extracted in C++

Tags: python, c++, gdb, boost-python, pybind11

I casted/extracted a python class inherited from a C++ class that I want to debbug, I am only using gdb to do that task. I tried to add a breakpoint in the python file, but obviously it did not work.
Recently I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61817085/13522550) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61769980/13522550) to cast/extract a python class inherited from a C++, so I am not calling eval neither exec functions. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you own the c++ code, you could add some debug logging.

Comment: There is no way to debug the python code like the c++? Maybe I don't understand your proposition, but it seems not to work on every future python extension. I would like to set a break point on a python file. Any way, thank you for the idea.

Comment: If you want to debug extensions you need to run the python interpreter under gdb. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412708/debugging-stepping-through-python-script-using-gdb

Comment: That solution didn't work for me the program I want to debug is not python, it is a program that uses a python extension through pybind. I tried this solution https://gitter.im/pybind/Lobby?at=5ec00264f3ce603074c16817 and it didn't work for me.

Comment: No cpython function is called by my program so I must use another solution... Any idea?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) ?